# PHP LDAP Options Not Defined

Tags: php, ssl, ldap, openldap

I'm attempting to use the PHP LDAP module to put an authentication layer over some of my organization's content. The script works perfectly if I set LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT to 0, but if I don't, I get the following errors.

- [ldap_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php) returns "Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server"
- [ldap_get_option()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php) for LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING returns "TLS error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."

[This page](https://serverfault.com/questions/754903/openldap-tls-error-8179peers-certificate-issuer-is-not-recognized) suggests that the Peer's Certificate error can be resolved by putting the LDAP server's security certificates on my own server. I requested the PEM from the IT department. Now I need to determine where to put it.

When I try to get the expected certificate directory by printing ldap_get_option() for LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, I get the warning "ldap_get_option() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given". Indeed, when I echo LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR itself, the result is literally that string, not an integer.

For example:

```
echo LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT . '<br />';
echo LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING . '<br />';
echo LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR;
die();
```

Result:

```
3
50
LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR
```

This is a problem for every LDAP_OPT_X_? option listed in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php) with the exception of LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, which prints out as 24582.

Does anyone know why these options are not defined?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: We're using version 7.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ldap-Option LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR was introduced in PHP 7.1 to PHPs LDAP-Extension (https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/8e9e89610e2e196892dbb7b605c65923a3fedf87). So when you're using PHP 7.0 there's not really a chance to get that up and running without hacking the PHP-Sources yourself. The easiest choice would be to update to PHP 7.1

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to 7.1.4 and I can get and set the options now.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this issue, it's also worth looking at TLS_CACERTDIR & TLS_REQCERT in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf if your PHP was compiled against OpenLDAP